# loop through subdirectories and create PDF for jpg for each subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to create a PDF from many JPGs per directory

```
/folder01/1.jpg
/folder01/2.jpg
/folder01/3.jpg
-->folder01.pdf

/folderxy/1.jpg
/folderxy/2.jpg
/folderxy/3.jpg
-->folderxy.pdf
```

What I already can do is manually create a PDF for each folder with:

```
cd folder01
img2pdf $(find . -iname '*.jpg' | sort -V) -o ./folder01.pdf

cd..
cd folder02
img2pdf $(find . -iname '*.jpg' | sort -V) -o ./folder02.pdf
```

How can I do this with only **ONE** command?

Thx and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is overkill for this task. Use globbing and parameter expansions:

```
for dir in */; do
    img2pdf "$dir"*.jpg -o "$dir${dir%?}.pdf"
done
```

Comment: Is there also a possibility to do this in an one line command?

Comment: @duffy6 Yes. Write the code above in one line and add a `;` before `done`. That is, `for dir in */; do img2pdf "$dir"*.jpg -o "$dir${dir%?}.pdf"; done` in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `while` `read` loop:

```sh
find . -type d | while read -r directory; do
    img2pdf $(find "$directory" -iname '*.jpg' | sort -V) -o "$directory/$directory.pdf"
done
```

If its really important to you that this is a one-line command, you can either place this loop in a function (which you can then call in a single line), or replace some newlines with semi-colons:

```sh
find . -type d | while read -r directory; do img2pdf $(find "$directory" -iname '*.jpg' | sort -V) -o "$directory/$directory.pdf"; done
```